# CAPTCHA says displayed below; it's displayed above

Tags: bug, captcha

I was presented with the following notice:

> "Are you a human being? We apologize for the confusion, but we can't
>   quite tell if you're a person or a script.
>
> Please don't take this personally.
>
> Bots and scripts can be remarkably lifelike these days!
>
> Enter the CAPTCHA displayed below, and we'll be out of your way."

All fair enough, I had tried to post an answer whilst disconnected, connected and posted. A reasonable response.

Picky me, though. The "CAPTCHA" appears *ABOVE* the text. Is this an "extra" way to check for a human?

Now with added screenshot!

Now, I didn't tag it Bug. Seems if I use CTRL-+ to make the screen big enough, then it flips. CTRL-- sets it back as expected.

[image: CAPTCHA above]

Comment: <chuckle/> Yes. A script would be misled by the explanatory text into scanning the wrong part of the page, whereas a human would use initiative to find it or cleverly ignore the text of the notice. <grin/>

Comment: I don't understand what you're getting at.

Comment: @djechlin the instructions said that the CAPTCHA would be displayed below, but it was really above

Comment: Hmm... what site was this on? The captcha message *is* displayed below [on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/captcha) and [on Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/captcha). Though I guess it might appear higher than the text if the robot image doesn't appear.

Comment: Site was StackOverflow. I got a big dark area, then the CAPTCHA, then the text, then a small dark area below. I actually sat there waiting for the thing to finish loading. I avoided "bug" up front, as I assumed this wasn't the normal way it worked. Maybe I'll try to recreate it.

Comment: OK, fresh from the embarrasment of actually entering the "answer" here by mistake, I got different results. I got a box, with a picture to the left, text to the right, CAPTCHA under the picture (so under, and to the left of, the text). Last night was Picture, text underneath the picture, CAPTCHA underneath the text. Picture was two blokes very convincingly disguised as robots (wearing cardboard boxes). Different machine, different browser, different OS. Problem was with Windows XP, Internet Explorer 8, portable with a "wider aspect" screen.

Comment: Next time screenshot. :)

Comment: Well, a Picture Paints a thousand words, although I think I did OK getting it all in a comment. I can't "screenshot" the failure, until I try it on the other machine. If to do with "image size", maybe I can't reproduce, so hence the description of the image (there must be a limited number of them for selection...?).